# How to get a list of everyone who liked a facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I will try to be as concise as possible.

Objective: Get a list of names of everyone who liked my Facebook page. This will be done in an application installed on that page. The app will then be used to create a lottery and chose a winner.

What I have so far is: appId, appSecret and an Acces-Token with me as an admin of that page. 
I have also found online that a query like this one would in fact do what I need:

> *SELECT user_id from like where object_id = \'PAGE_ID\';'*

**My question is : How do I run the query in order to make it work?**

So far I have tried but all I get is an empty array...

```
$result2 = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'access_token' => 'TOKEN',
        'query' => 'SELECT user_id from like where object_id = \'APP_ID\';'
        ));
        ;
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible - you can only check if a specific user likes the page, or retrieve a list of the pages a users likes (with appropriate permission), you can't retrieve a complete list of the users that like a specific page

{edit} As 'Query Master' said in a now-deleted answer, if your app is installed on a page tab, you can find out (via the `signed_request` sent to the app - [details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) ) if the current user likes the page, but you still can't get their user ID unless they authorise your app{/edit}

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to find another solution

Comment: Hi, Lgy, how can I determine user liked page or not?

Comment: See the answers on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page